# Excel spreadsheet IF OR formula for specific text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel spreadsheet that contains the row headings 'Acronym' and 'Alphabet' [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dtag.png), but I need a formula that says; if the first letter of the 'Acronym' begins with letter 'A' then the 'Alphabet' cell will automatically update to 'A', OR if the 'Acronym' begins with 'B' then the 'Alphabet' will change to 'B' etc etc.

This is what I have so far but it only workS for 'A', i need it for the other letters of the alphabet.

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("A,C:C)),"A",FALSE)

It needs to include OR statements but I can't work out how to ad them in so it will work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After read the question I came to the conclusion that you want pick the First Character or Alphabet from **Column Acronym** to **Column Alphabet** for example if A then A to the adjacent column.

I'm assuming TWO situations,,

1. Alphabet Column has No Data (is blank).
2. Alphabet Column is populated with data.

**For the 1st situation** you can use this simplest formula.

I'm assuming Acronym is in Column A & Alphabet in in Column B and

=Left(A2,1)

**NB:**[Formula in B2 cell] and drag it down to fill.

**For the 2nd situation** when Alphabet column has data may be single character or a word, in this situation you need to pick the first character from Acronym column & add with existing data. For this you can use following formula.

=Left(A2,1) & B2

or

=CONCATENATE(Left(A2,1), B2)

**NB:**[Formula in C2 cell] and drag it down to fill.

**Hope this** help you and "*note I've assumed this two possible situations just to enhance the scope of the formulation to help you in better way only*".

Comment: Keep asking @user815942

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your Acronym data starts in C2, you can use

```
=left(C2,1)
```

then fill down